# I had a problem in the process of executing the mariadb docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mariadb

I had a problem in the process of executing the mariadb docker image.

This is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM mariadb
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD test1357
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE mydb
EXPOSE 3306
ENTRYPOINT ["mysqld", "--user=root"]
```

and I try build and run this Dockerfile.

```
docker build -t mariadb:1.0 .
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name mariadb mariadb:1.0
```

then, my mariadb container exited.
so, I try check logs with the following command.
And, I encountered the error.

```
docker logs -f mariadb

...

2021-05-23  7:10:08 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded
2021-05-23  7:10:08 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2021-05-23  7:10:08 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-05-23  7:10:08 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.db' doesn't exist
2021-05-23  7:10:08 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

What should I do to solve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the things you're setting, don't create a custom image at all; just run the standard Docker Hub `mariadb` image.

```sh
docker rmi mariadb:1.0
docker network create some-network
docker run \
  -d \
  -p 3306:3306 \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test1357 \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=db \
  --name db \
  --net some-network \
  mariadb
```

You do not generally want to put passwords or other credentials like ssh keys in a Dockerfile: anyone who has the resulting image can easily get the password back out.  If the only thing you need in your custom Dockerfile is to set environment variables, just provide them when you run the command.

If you do build a derived image from something that already has a main application in it (`FROM mariadb`, `tomcat`, `nginx`, ...) the `EXPOSE`, `ENTRYPOINT`, and `CMD` settings are inherited from that base image.  The [`mariadb` Dockerfile](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/8be7abacca5f19d487b137c7d8f9516d07116109/10.6/Dockerfile#L124) already declares `CMD ["mysqld"]` and you don't need to repeat this.  By overriding `ENTRYPOINT`, you're actually replacing the script that creates the initial database and uses these environment variables.  Here you don't need to provide a command at all; if you do, generally prefer `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT` (it is easier to override when you run a container and there is a common pattern of using `ENTRYPOINT` as a setup script).

Comment: thank you so much.
Your answer was helpful to me.